# Find Missing Data between interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, missing-data

I have a system that inserts register in same minutes every hour, for example:

```
DateTime              Value
2023/05/01 06:14        10
2023/05/01 06:29        15
2023/05/01 06:44        21
2023/05/01 06:59        12
```

So i want make a query that returns me possible missing records in a given range.

```
DateTime              Value
2023/05/01 06:14        10
2023/05/01 06:29        15
2023/05/01 06:44        21
2023/05/01 06:59        12
2023/05/01 07:29        10
2023/05/01 07:44        17
2023/05/01 08:14        20
```

In this record i want a query returns me:

```
DateTime
2023/05/01 07:14
2023/05/01 07:59
```

I've read some threads with similar problems like this one: [Find Missing Dates in Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643876/find-missing-dates-in-data)

But i can't find the solution.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set interval based on the minutes(I set 15 minute )

I got the start date and end date based on your data, you can set it as well

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME 
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @interval int=15

SET @StartDate =(select min(_DateTime) from #test)
SET @EndDate = (select max(_DateTime) from #test)

;WITH Dates(Date) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @interval, @StartDate) AS Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @interval, Date) AS Date
    FROM Dates
    WHERE Date < @EndDate
)
SELECT a.Date
FROM  Dates a
left join #test b on a.Date=b._DateTime
where b._DateTime is null
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

result:
|Date|
|--|
|2023-05-01 07:14:00.000|
|2023-05-01 07:59:00.000|

Base Data:

```
create table #test(_DateTime DateTime,_value int)
insert into #test(_DateTime,_value) values('2023/05/01 06:14',        10)
insert into #test(_DateTime,_value) values('2023/05/01 06:29',        15)
insert into #test(_DateTime,_value) values('2023/05/01 06:44',        21)
insert into #test(_DateTime,_value) values('2023/05/01 06:59',        12)
insert into #test(_DateTime,_value) values('2023/05/01 07:29',        10)
insert into #test(_DateTime,_value) values('2023/05/01 07:44',        17)
insert into #test(_DateTime,_value) values('2023/05/01 08:14',        20)
```

Comment: Hi! This solved my problem.  I just changed the way to set the start date so that the user can set the query start date to any value

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution. I assume there's not more than 24 hours difference between two days, if that ain't so, you need to increase the CTE values:

```sql
DECLARE @times TABLE (
    datetime datetime, value int)
INSERT INTO @times
SELECT  datetime, value
FROM    (
        VALUES  ('2023/05/01 06:14',10)
        ,   ('2023/05/01 06:29',15)
        ,   ('2023/05/01 06:44',21)
        ,   ('2023/05/01 06:59',12)
        ,   ('2023/05/01 07:29',10)
        ,   ('2023/05/01 07:44',17)
        ,   ('2023/05/01 08:14',20)
        ,   ('2023/05/01 18:14',20)
    ) t (datetime, value)
    
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@spid) AS row
    FROM    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(v)
    CROSS apply (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) y(y)
)
SELECT  prevDate, missingDate, datetime
FROM    (
    SELECT  DATEDIFF(HOUR, LAG(datetime) OVER(ORDER BY datetime), datetime) AS diff
    ,   LAG(datetime) OVER(ORDER BY datetime) AS prevDate
    ,   *
    FROM    @times
    ) z
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  missingDate
    ,   c.*
    FROM    cte c
    CROSS apply (VALUES(14),(29),(44),(59)) m(m)
    CROSS apply (
        SELECT  DATEADD(hour, c.row-1, DATEADD(minute, m.m, DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, z.prevDate), z.prevDate))) AS missingDate
        ) sd
    WHERE   c.row BETWEEN 1 AND diff + 1
    AND missingDate > prevDate 
    AND missingDate < datetime
    ) q
ORDER BY datetime
```

What this does is take the gap between each datetime and it's previous value, and then generates a list of missing times in between those two days with help of a series CTE, and a list of fixed hours ((14),(29),(44),(59)).

`DATEADD(hour, c.row-1, DATEADD(minute, m.m, DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, z.prevDate), z.prevDate)))` this part generates the missing date by removing minutes from previous date and then add the hours and fixed minutes between the two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Generate all possible times, then do a left join to your table:

```
DECLARE @start_time DATETIME = '2023-05-01 06:14';
DECLARE @end_time DATETIME = '2023-05-01 08:14'
DECLARE @interval_in_sec INT = 60*15;

WITH all_times AS -- using row_number from the [master]..spt_values table to generate all possible times.
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start_time, @end_time) / @interval_in_sec)  
     DATEADD(SECOND, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) * @interval_in_sec,  @start_time) AS dt
  FROM [master]..spt_values -- system tables can be changed by the vendor without pre-warning, it would be better to create your own numbers table
)
SELECT TS.dt AS Date_Time
FROM all_times TS LEFT JOIN table_name TB
ON TS.dt = TB.Date_Time
WHERE TB.Date_Time IS NULL
ORDER BY TS.dt
```

In SQL Server 2022, we could use the `GENERATE_SERIES` function:

```
WITH all_times AS
(
  SELECT 
     DATEADD(SECOND, value * @interval_in_sec,  @start_time) AS dt
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0,DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start_time, @end_time) / @interval_in_sec,1)
)
...
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LkO-7V3I)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, a time interval of 15 minutes should be present between each entry. i.e. this is the case for the time ranges of 07:14-07:29 and 07:59-08:14, whereby 07:14 and 07:59 have been specified as the missing time ranges.

An effective way to accomplish this is to firstly identify the difference in time intervals between each subsequent timestamp. This can be accomplished using a LEAD function within a subquery.

For illustrative purposes, let's consider the following example. Suppose there exists a column of dates as below:

[image: date]

Now, let us assume that one wishes to add 15 minutes to the date where a time interval of greater than 15 minutes exists.

This can be accomplished as follows:

```
SELECT date, next_date, next_date - date as difference, date + interval '15' minute from (select date, LEAD(date, 1) 
OVER (ORDER BY date) 
AS next_date from table) as subquery where next_date-date>'15 minutes';
```

[image: result]

In this table, the last column adds 15 minutes to the original timestamp - but those timestamps with an interval of 15 minutes or less are not displayed.

As such, one could choose to only display this column to show the desired timestamp of *original timestamp + 15 minutes*, but only where the difference between timestamps was **greater** than 15 minutes.